# Using ag-grid, is it possible to implement editing when using virtual paging/infinite scrolling?

Tags: virtual, edit, infinite-scroll, ag-grid

Reading ag-grid documentation, I see that it is explicitly specified that aggregation and grouping is not allowed when using virtual paging/infinite scroll.

Does anyone know if editing of rows is supported when using virtual paging/infinite scroll?  Has anyone implemented it?